# Mixing `using / try-catch-finally`

Tags: c#, oracle, resources, dispose, odp.net

I'm using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` in my application. Here is how I handle releasing/closing resources/connections:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

try
{
    conn.Open();
    ...
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString, conn))
    {
        using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
        {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    ...// reading data here
                }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // log error
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

Questions:

1. Can I mix `using` and `try/catch` as shown above?
2. ODP.NET samples showing `Close` methot is used for `reader`. Does `usage` which is calling `dispose`(hopefully) also closing reader?
3. Does above implementation guarantee closing Oracle connection in most of cases?

Comment: Yes, you can use both Catch and Finally. But if `OracleConnection` is disposable then I would use `using` to automatically Close and Dispose.

Comment: I also need to know whether `OracleConnection` will `close` connection upon disposal, right?

Comment: _I also need to know whether OracleConnection will close connection upon disposal, right?_ If the OracleConnection is disposable, then it should be safe to assume it closes down connections. It would be a very badly written connection class to be disposable but not close it's own connections.

Comment: 3. It depends. If you use connection pool (default) the connection is returned to the pool, the physical session remains in the database and is reconnected when another instance of OracleConnection opens. But you can't access it anymore with the disposed instance. If you use non-pooled connection, then the session is terminated

Comment: @Husqvik: How to force non-pooled connection?

Comment: @Pablo: add POOLING=False to your connection string but be aware of the consequences

Comment: The problem that make me redesign this part is sometimes sessions are remaining open and I am receiving e-mail warnings from Oracle administration. So even if it's pooled connection and `Close/Dispose` has been called, does Oracle server consider the session as open or closed?

Comment: As I said if you use pooling the session in the database is not terminated. You can set connection lifetime after which Oracle should terminate the session if there is no activity. Otherwise the session is kept forever (until the process exit). Close/Dispose handles only .NET and client non managed resources.

Comment: Have a look in the docs for the connection string parameters. There's a minpoolsize and maxpoolsize you can set. You can also turn on performance counters to help you tune your pool under realistic load with appropriate values for these parameters.